# Show Diagonal Matrix is not possible

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider the real matrix $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}$. Show/explain that there does **not** exist a invertible real matrix $\beta$, so that $\beta ^{-1} \alpha \beta$ is a diagonal matrix

**My effort so far**

I know that to diagonalize a matirx $A$

Find the eigenvalues of $A$ using the characteristic polynomial.

For each eigenvalue $λ$ of $A$ , compute a basis $B λ$ for the $λ$-eigenspace.

If there are fewer than $n$ total vectors in all of the eigenspace bases $B λ$ , then the matrix is not diagonalizable. I am losing it when it comes to the specific case "Show/explain that there does **not** exist a invertible real matrix $\beta$, so that $\beta ^{-1} \alpha \beta$ is a diagonal matrix". How would I go about this one in question?

Comment: When you find the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$ the problem will be pretty much immediately solved, so do it.

Comment: @user5713492 It is now found - what would one now conclude from that? I get that the values $i,-i$ are eigenvalues of $\alpha$ but how does that show that there does not exist a invertible real matrix so that the above is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: My solution would then be to point out that $$\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta=\delta$$ where the diagonal elements of $\delta$ are the eigenvalues. If $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ then $\delta\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$, but it's not so you know that some elements of $\beta$ must be complex.

Comment: @user5713492 "but it is not so..." why is it not. That is my last confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your specific question at the end of your post:

You may go about it by first assuming that such a $\beta$ exists and lead this assumption to a contradiction.

But first of all, it seems your question is about whether the given matrix can be diagonalized over $\mathbb{R}$. Because, over $\mathbb{C}$ you will find $3$ linearly independent (complex) eigenvectors.

Now, back to your question:

Assume there is an invertible $\beta = (b_1\: b_2\: b_3)$ with columns $b_1,b_2,b_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$.  s.t.
$$\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\Leftrightarrow
\alpha\beta=\beta\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$$

But since $$\beta\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) = (\lambda_1b_1\: \lambda_2b_2\: \lambda_3b_3)$$ this means
$$\alpha(b_1\: b_2\: b_3)=(\lambda_1b_1\: \lambda_2b_2\: \lambda_3b_3)$$

Hence, the columns of $\beta$ form a basis of **real** eigenvectors of $\alpha$. But since you find only one linearly independent **real** eigenvector of $\alpha$, such a $\beta$ **does not exist**.

Comment: exactly it is over the real numbers. Thanks!

Comment: one small question about the last sentence. Why does $\beta$ not exist as a consequence of that we only find one real eigenvector of $\alpha$ that is linearly independent?

Comment: Because, according to the calculation shown, the existence of $\beta$ would require the existence of three linearly independent real eigenvectors. Since these real eigenvectors do not exist, our assumption that such a $\beta$ exists is wrong. Hence, such a $\beta$ does not exist.
This is a typical reasoning within a proof by contradiction. You will see this often in maths.

Comment: Just as a reminder: $\beta$ is required to be invertible. Hence, the columns of $\beta$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Hello - quick question; why does the colums of $\beta$ form a basis of real eigenvectors of $\alpha$

Comment: Because of $$\beta\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) = (\lambda_1b_1\: \lambda_2b_2\: \lambda_3b_3)$$
To understand this just take any $3\times 3$-matrix and multiply it with a $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix from the right. Then you will see.

Comment: I would really like to understand the characteristic polynomial direct approach but do not get the conclusion since the values of i are solutions

Comment: Just saw that you asked the question again. So, hopefully the answer there can clear up any further doubts. But you won't get around the calculation in my answer :-) ... or you just accept the equality of characteristic polynomials for similar matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$ is $(X^2+1)(X-3)$ therefore $i$ and $-i$ are eigenvalues of $\alpha$ and thus $\alpha$ is not diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R}$ (but is in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: so everything that is to do is find the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$ and since $i,-i$ are eigenvalues of $\alpha$ it is not diagonalizable in the real numbers? Why is the last conclusion true?

Comment: If such a $\beta$ exists, then the columns of $\beta$ are the eigenvectors of $\alpha$, therefore there would exist $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\alpha x=ix$ since $i$ is an eigenvalue of $\alpha$. If $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, then looking at the $k$-th coordinate in the above equation gives $\alpha_{k,1}x_1+\alpha_{k,2}x_2+\alpha_{k,3}x_3=i x_k$. Since the LHS is in $\mathbb{R}$, then the RHS is also real which is possible only if $x_k=0$. Therefore $x=0$ which is a contradiction since $x$ is an eigenvector which is hence not $0$.